# How can I generate monotonic random real numbers

Tags: function-construction, random, random-process

My question is simple, and therefore I made a search of an answer to it using the Repository of this forum. There are relevant questions, however, none of them answers to the following question.

My first question is how to generate a list of lists (matrix) of `RandomReal` numbers, but the repetitively generated lists should be monotonic (increasing or decreasing).

```
SeedRandom[213];
RandomReal[{0.3, 0.8}, 4];
(*output={0.5318, 0.412309, 0.571831, 0.673618}*)
```

In the next round of `RealRandom` generation, every element in the list `output` should be increased (or decreased) randomly within a small range, call the new output as `output1`. In still another round, `RandomReal` should generate another list `output2`, every element of which should be greater than every corresponding element of `output1` and so on.

My second question is more difficult (for me) since I also want some of the elements in the randomly generated list to remain unchanged, while others monotonically change. Namely, I like to control some elements during the process of random number generation.

Eventually, I like to combine the answers to these questions in a `Mathematica` function, such as `rng[...]:=` to automate the random number generations in the range of my interest.

**EDIT 1**

The type of `Mathematica` function I have in mind has the following form:

```
f[inc_List, rngi_Range, rti_Real, dec_List, rngd_Range, rtd_Real, 
    fix_List, lrv_Integer, ni_Integer]
```

where

> - inc_List    = list of elements to be increased;
>
>   - rngi_Range  = a range for the increment of `inc_List`;
>   - rti_Real    = rate of increase (real number in the interval [0,1]);
>   - dec_List    = list of elements to be decreased;
>   - rngd_Range  = a range for the decrease of `dec_List`;
>   - rtd_Real    = rate of decrease (real number in the interval [0,1]);
>   - fix         = list of elements to be fixed;
>   - ni_Integer  = number of times for Random # generation/number of iterations;
>   - lrv_Integer = length of the random vector;

Comment: when generating `output2` in round 2 do you use `rti` and `rngi` to increase _**all**_ elements of `output1` or only the elements in in `inc`?

Comment: @kglr: In round 2, I want to use `rti` and `rngi` to increase the elements in `inc` only. Similarly, I like to use `rtd` and `rngd` to decrease the elements in `dec` only.

Comment: Why not just generate a list of random numbers and then sort them from low to high?

Comment: @JimB: I have a list of elements `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}`, some of which should increase like `{a,b,c}`, some decrease like `{d,e,f}`, while still others like `{g,h}` are fixed. A new value for each element in each group should be randomly selected but in the desired direction such as increase, decrease and fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[step, iterate]
step[initialvector_, indicesdecay_, rangedecay_, indicesgrow_,  rangegrow_] := 
 Module[{ca = Normal[
      SparseArray[Join[Thread[indicesdecay -> -1], Thread[indicesgrow -> 1]], 
        Length@initialvector]]}, 
  initialvector (1 + (ca /. {1 :> RandomReal[rangegrow],
      -1 :> RandomReal[rangedecay]}))]

iterate[initialvector_, indicesdecay_, rangedecay_, indicesgrow_, 
  rangegrow_, iterations_] := 
 NestList[step[#, indicesdecay, rangedecay, indicesgrow, rangegrow] &,
   initialvector, iterations]
```

***Example:***

Given an initial vector (`{1,2,3,4,5}`), column 4 stays constant, columns 1 and 3 decay at a random rate in range `{-.3, -.2}` at each step, and columns 2 and 5 grow at a random rate in range `{.1,.5}`, iterated 7 steps:

```
SeedRandom[1]
ListLinePlot[Transpose@ iterate[Range[5], {1, 3}, {-.3, -.2}, {2, 5}, {.1, .5}, 7], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

For arithmetic progression (columns in `indicesdecay` decrease by a random amount and columns in `indicesgrow` increase by a random amount at every step) ypu can use:

```
ClearAll[step2, iterate2]
step2[initialvector_, indicesdecay_, rangedecay_, indicesgrow_, rangegrow_] := 
 Module[{ca = Normal[SparseArray[
      Join[Thread[indicesdecay -> -1], Thread[indicesgrow -> 1]], 
      Length@initialvector]]}, 
  initialvector + (ca /. {1 :> RandomReal[rangegrow], -1 :> 
       RandomReal[rangedecay]})]

iterate2[initialvector_, indicesdecay_, rangedecay_, indicesgrow_, 
  rangegrow_, iterations_] := 
 NestList[step2[#, indicesdecay, rangedecay, indicesgrow, 
    rangegrow] &, initialvector, iterations]
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
ListLinePlot[Transpose@iterate2[Range[5], {1, 3}, {-.3, -.2}, {2, 5}, {.1, .5}, 7], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Making parameter selections interactive:

```
DynamicModule[{m = ConstantArray[0, 20], iv0, iv, dv, sim}, 
 Manipulate[dv = m[[;; vl[[1]]]]; 
  SeedRandom[seed]; 
  iv0 = RandomReal[ir, {1, vl[[2]]}]; 
  iv = iv0[[{1}, ;; vl[[1]]]];
  sim = NestList[# (1 + (dv /. {1 :> RandomReal[gr], -1 -> 
            RandomReal[dr]})) &, iv[[1]], iter[[1]]];
  Column[{Style["initial vector", 16], 
    ListLinePlot[iv, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, { Range[vl[[1]]], None}}, 
     AspectRatio -> All, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, 
     PlotRange -> {{.5, vl[[1]] + .5}, {0, All}}], 
    MatrixPlot[iv, Mesh -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
     FrameTicks -> {{{{1, Invisible[0.5]}}, None}, {Range[vl[[1]]], 
        None}}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50], Style["directions", 16], 
    EventHandler[Dynamic@MatrixPlot[{dv}, Mesh -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
       FrameTicks -> {{{{1, Invisible[0.5]}}, None}, { 
          Range[vl[[1]]], None}}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, 
       Epilog -> Dynamic[MapIndexed[
          Text[Style[#, Large], Reverse@#2 - .5] &, {dv}, {2}]]], 
     {"MouseClicked" :> With[{p = First@Ceiling@MousePosition["Graphics"]}, 
        m[[p]] = Mod[m[[p]] + 1, 3, -1]]}], Style["simulation", 16], 
    Row[{ListLinePlot[Transpose@sim, Frame -> True, 
       FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, { Range[iter[[1]]], None}}, 
       AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> (iter[[1]]/vl[[1]]) -> 50, 
       PlotRange -> {{.5, iter[[1]] + 1}, All}], 
      TableForm[sim, TableHeadings -> {Range[iter[[1]]], Range[vl[[1]]]}]}, Spacer[10]]}],
  {{seed, 1, "seed"}, 1, 100, 1, Manipulator, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}},
  {{vl, {5, 10}, "vector Length"}, 1, 20, 1, IntervalSlider[##, Method -> "Stop"] &, 
   Appearance -> {"Paired", "Labeled"}},
  {{iter, {10, 15}, "iterations"}, 1, 50, 1, IntervalSlider[##, Method -> "Stop"] &, 
   Appearance -> {"Paired", "Labeled"}},
  {{ir, {.3, .9}, "inital range"}, 0, 1, IntervalSlider[##, Method -> "Stop"] &, 
   Appearance -> {"Paired", "Labeled"}},
  {{gr, {.1, .3}, "growth range"}, 0, 1, IntervalSlider[##, Method -> "Stop"] &, 
   Appearance -> {"Paired", "Labeled"}}, 
  {{dr, {-.3, -.05}, "decay range"}, -1, 0, IntervalSlider[##, Method -> "Stop"] &, 
   Appearance -> {"Paired", "Labeled"}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is more than excellent. I do not know how to thank you for this very very useful code. Thank you again.

Comment: When I run `DynamicModule`, the colored row above showing {-1, 1, 0, -1, 1}` becomes `{0,0,0,0,0}`. Do you think my `Mathematica` version 11 is the cause or something else?

Comment: I got it! When I click on the colored vector, I get the results. Sorry for this.

Comment: @Tugrul, thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Starting as you do, let's write:

```
SeedRandom[123];
list1 = RandomReal[{0.3, 0.8}, 4]
```

which produces

```
{0.52786, 0.788913, 0.771607, 0.781108}
```

Next, we want to increase each of these a small amount.  You could do this:

```
smallRange = {0.05, 0.1};
list2 = list1 + RandomReal[smallRange, 4]
```

My session produces

```
{0.592977, 0.862248, 0.824689, 0.85039}
```

Next, only increase some of the numbers in the list by a small amount

```
list3 = list2 + RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 4]*RandomReal[smallRange, 4]
```

which results in

```
{0.644909, 0.930171, 0.896649, 0.85039}
```

If you need help turning these fragments into a neat function then

- clarify your requirements, as I expect I have missed some of the fine detail (eg which elements are not to increase - selected ones or random as I have assumed); and
- ask for that help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few pieces of the puzzle. To generate monotonic sequences of "random" numbers:

```
Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 0.1}, 10]
{0.0669849, 0.0935961, 0.141986, 0.216063, 0.238291, 
            0.255048, 0.269631, 0.276363, 0.284295, 0.329844}
```

Now let's say you have a vector x and you want the first few to go up a tiny bit and the rest to go down. Specify the direction using the vector dir

```
x = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10];
dir = Flatten@{ConstantArray[1, 4], ConstantArray[-1, 6]};

ran = dir RandomReal[{0, 0.1}, 10];
x+ran
```

Now x+ran is a perturbed vector of the same kind as x, but with the first four perturbed up and the rest perturbed down. To have some remain unchanged, set the corresponding elements of dir to zero.

Comment: Thanks for useful few pieces of the puzzle. The function described in the question requires the representation of all the pieces together in a functional form. The problem lies in the "repeated" generation of a ready-to-use set random numbers in a system of equations to assess the slope change in some variables.